# Fail to create an F# project under Monodevelop on OSX

Tags: macos, f#, monodevelop

I get the following error from MonoDevelop

```
System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProject.CreateConfiguration (System.String name) [0x000cc] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.1-series/5d928ec4/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/DotNetProject.cs:753 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProject..ctor (System.String languageName, MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation projectCreateInfo, System.Xml.XmlElement projectOptions) [0x0011f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.1-series/5d928ec4/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/DotNetProject.cs:120 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetAssemblyProject..ctor (System.String languageName, MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation projectCreateInfo, System.Xml.XmlElement projectOptions) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProjectBinding.CreateProject (System.String languageName, MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation info, System.Xml.XmlElement projectOptions) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.1-series/5d928ec4/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/DotNetProjectBinding.cs:51 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProjectBinding.CreateProject (MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation info, System.Xml.XmlElement projectOptions) [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.1-series/5d928ec4/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/DotNetProjectBinding.cs:46 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectService.CreateProject (System.String type, MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation info, System.Xml.XmlElement projectOptions) [0x00033] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.1-series/5d928ec4/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectService.cs:498 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.ProjectDescriptor.CreateItem (MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation projectCreateInformation, System.String defaultLanguage) [0x00036] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.1-series/5d928ec4/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates/ProjectDescriptor.cs:116 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.SolutionDescriptor.CreateEntry (MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation projectCreateInformation, System.String defaultLanguage) [0x001bc] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.1-series/5d928ec4/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates/SolutionDescriptor.cs:152 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.ProjectTemplate.CreateWorkspaceItem (MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation cInfo) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.1-series/5d928ec4/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates/ProjectTemplate.cs:232 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Projects.NewProjectDialog.CreateProject () [0x001ef] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.1-series/5d928ec4/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Projects/NewProjectDialog.cs:432
```

If I try to load an existing F# project then I get the error

```
Error while trying to load the project
 '/Users/bradphelan/workspace/myfirstfsharp/myfirstfsharp/myfirstfsharp.fsproj': 
 Could not load type 'MonoDevelop.FSharp.FSharpCompilerParameters' 
 from assembly 'FSharpBinding, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Note that I can create a C# project.

*** EDIT UPDATE ***

Got errors rebuilding the fsharp bindings

```
Errors:

/Users/bradphelan/workspace/fsharpbinding/monodevelop/MonoDevelop.FSharpBinding/MonoDevelop.FSharp.local.fsproj (default targets) ->
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets (ResolveProjectReferences target) ->
/Users/bradphelan/workspace/fsharpbinding/FSharp.CompilerBinding/FSharp.CompilerBinding.fsproj (default targets) ->
/Users/bradphelan/workspace/fsharpbinding/lib/fsharp/Microsoft.FSharp.Targets (CoreCompile target) ->

    : error : Error initializing task ItemGroup: Not registered task ItemGroup.

/Users/bradphelan/workspace/fsharpbinding/monodevelop/MonoDevelop.FSharpBinding/MonoDevelop.FSharp.local.fsproj (default targets) ->
/Users/bradphelan/workspace/fsharpbinding/lib/fsharp/Microsoft.FSharp.Targets (CreateManifestResourceNames target) ->

    : error : Error initializing task ItemGroup: Not registered task ItemGroup.
```

Comment: Which MonoDevelop, Mono and F# versions? Do you use binary distribution or compile from source?

Comment: I installed the latest beta versions from http://monodevelop.com/Download  MonoDevelop 3.1.1 and Mono 3.0.3 The release notes say the F# is included.

Comment: Have you installed F# binding in `MonoDevelop --> Add-in manager --> Gallery --> Language Bindings --> F# Language Binding`? If there is still error, you may have to compile the latest binding to get the fix https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/issues/86

Comment: How to compile the latest binding?

Comment: See intructions in the README page: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding#building-and-installing-from-scratch

Comment: I got errors running make

Comment: You have a better luck getting an answer by opening an issue in `fsharpbinding` repo.

Comment: This is an old question but you were running the compiler using Mono 2.10.9.   The F# binding currently only compiles with Mono 3.x version bus to an XBuild dependency in that version.